# How to find where is an object declare in GSP

Tags: grails, gsp

In a gsp file there is line like below

```
<g:each in="${tools}" var="tool" status="counter">
```

and when i debug it shows value like below

[image]

It's using Grails framework. May I know how can I find where is this `${tools}` declared and being called from to this GSP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails uses convention over configuration. So in order to trace back where `tool` is being set, you have to note the name of the gsp file and the directory in which it is placed.

Ideally if the gsp name is `bar.gsp` and is placed under `foo` directory under `grails-app/views` then the convention is that there could be a `FooController.groovy` under `grails-app/controllers` which would have an action called `bar()`. Most likely the model is set with the variable `tools` inside the `bar`action.

This exercise would be a good starting point.

Comment: the gsp is under view>leader>_tool_preview.gsp. I could not find a controller such as _tool_previewController

Answer (score 0):

What @dmahapatro suggested is the best approach but if you are still unable to find that `tools` variable and simply do a project level search in the IDE you are using and find the word `tools`.

Here are some filters you can apply to fasten your search:

1. First, search only in the directory `grails-app/controllers`
2. Then search in the directory `grails-app/directives`
3. Try to search following words: `tools`, `tools:`, `tools :` because it will be rendered as a map.